# Как делать zoom относительно позиции указателя мыши, можно пример?

Tags: java, swing

Доброго времени суток, есть панель, вложенная в JScrollPane, как сделать zoom содержимого панели, относительно позиции курсора мыши, а не верхнего левого угла(точки 0,0)? Можно пример?